# React function not capturing correct value

Tags: reactjs

I am wanting to access the updated value of selectedRouteId within handleDisconnectRoute but it is only ever the initial state. How can access the updated value of selectedRouteId within handleDisconnectRoute? If I output the selectedRouteId within the useEffect method it will update correctly, I'm sure it's a simple issue with handleDisconnectRoute being called on the initial render and not updating after, any help would be appreciated

```
import React, { useCallback, useEffect, useLayoutEffect, useState } from "react";
import { ITableHeader, RouteStop } from "@/shared/interfaces";
import GridTable from "@/shared/components/tables/GridTable";
import DeliveryAttemptDialog from "@/shared/components/dialogs/DeliveryAttemptDialog";
import { useAppDispatch, useAppSelector } from "@/redux/hooks";
import { RootState } from "@/redux/store";
import SettingList from "@/shared/components/list/SettingList";
import { deliveryActions } from "../../deliverySlice";

interface TableItem {
  id: number;
  Reference?: string;
  Customer?: string;
  M3?: number;
  KG?: number;
  Suburb?: string;
  backwards?: boolean;
}

function Orders({ orders }: { orders: RouteStop[] }) {
  const [items, setItems] = useState<TableItem[]>([]);
  const [columns, setColumns] = useState<ITableHeader[]>([
    {
      key: "Reference",
      label: "Reference",
      lg: 1.7,
    },
    {
      key: "Customer",
      label: "Customer",
      lg: 4.5,
      textOverFlow: true,
    },
    {
      key: "M3",
      label: "M3",
      lg: 1.2,
      sort: {
        orderBy: "asc",
      },
      columnType: "string",
    },
    {
      key: "KG",
      label: "KG",
      lg: 1.2,
      sort: {
        orderBy: "asc",
      },
      columnType: "string",
    },
    {
      key: "Suburb",
      label: "Suburb",
      lg: 1.4,
      sort: {
        orderBy: "asc",
      },
      columnType: "string",
    },
    {
      key: "Action",
      align: "right",
      cell: (item: TableItem) => renderButtons(item),
    },
  ]);
  const [selectedDeliveryId, setSelectedDeliveryId] = useState<number | undefined>();
  const [openOrderDetail, setOpenOrderDetail] = useState<boolean>(false);
  const loading = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.delivery.orderLoading);
  const { route } = useAppSelector((state: RootState) => state.delivery);
  const [selectedRouteId, setSelectedRouteId] = useState<number>(0);

  const dispatch = useAppDispatch();
  const handleOpenDetailsOrder = (orderId?: number) => {
    if (!orderId) return;
    setOpenOrderDetail(true);
    setSelectedDeliveryId(orderId);
  };
  const handleCloseDetailsOrder = () => setOpenOrderDetail(false);

  const renderButtons = useCallback(
    (item: TableItem) => (
      <SettingList
        content1="DETAILS"
        content2="DISCONNECT"
        onClickContent1={() => handleOpenDetailsOrder(item.id)}
        onClickContent2={() => handleDisconnectRoute(item)}
      />
    ),
    [selectedRouteId]
  );

  const handleDisconnectRoute = (item: TableItem) => {
    const deliveryId = item.id;

    console.log(selectedRouteId);
    console.log(deliveryId);

    const dataPayload = {
      deliveryId: deliveryId,
      selectedRouteId,
    };

    //dispatch(deliveryActions.disconnectRoute(dataPayload));
  };

  useEffect(() => {
    if (route?.id) {
      setSelectedRouteId(route.id);
    }
  }, [orders]);

  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!orders) return;

    const itemsView: any[] = [];
    orders.forEach((item) => {
      const customerName = item.deliveryAttempts?.[0].order?.shippingAddress?.name ?? item.customer?.name;

      const suburb = item.customerAddress?.suburb;
      itemsView.push(
        ...item.deliveryAttempts.map((dAItem) => ({
          id: dAItem.id,
          Reference: dAItem.order?.reference,
          Customer: customerName ?? `Transfer ${dAItem.order?.transferAddress ?? ""}`,
          M3: Number(dAItem.order?.totalCubic),
          KG: Number(dAItem.order?.totalWeight),
          Suburb: suburb,
          backwards: dAItem.attemptNo > 1,
        }))
      );
    });
    setItems(itemsView);
  }, [orders]);

  return (
    <React.Fragment>
      <GridTable
        sx={{
          backgroundColor: "#F7F7F7",
          marginTop: "21px",
          height: "100%",
        }}
        itemStyles={{
          paddingLeft: "54px",
        }}
        headers={columns}
        items={items}
        DnD
        droppableId="RouteOrdersTable"
        loading={loading}
        minHeight={812}
        maxHeight={812}
      />
      <DeliveryAttemptDialog deliveryAttemptId={selectedDeliveryId} open={openOrderDetail} handleClose={handleCloseDetailsOrder} />
    </React.Fragment>
  );
}

export default Orders;
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up figuring it out, it may not be the only solution but I added `selectedRouteId` to the TableItem interface

```
interface TableItem {
  id: number;
  Reference?: string;
  Customer?: string;
  M3?: number;
  KG?: number;
  Suburb?: string;
  backwards?: boolean;
  selectedRouteId?: number;
}
```

then updated this when the TableItems were updated:

```
  useLayoutEffect(() => {
    if (!orders) return;

    const itemsView: any[] = [];
    orders.forEach((item) => {
      const suburb = item.customerAddress?.suburb;
      itemsView.push(
        ...item.deliveryAttempts.map((dAItem) => ({
          id: dAItem.id,
          Reference: dAItem.order?.reference,
          Customer: dAItem.order?.shippingAddress?.name ?? dAItem.order?.customer?.name ?? `Transfer ${dAItem.order?.transferAddress ?? ""}`,
          M3: Number(dAItem.order?.totalCubic),
          KG: Number(dAItem.order?.totalWeight),
          Suburb: suburb,
          backwards: dAItem.attemptNo > 1,
          selectedRouteId: route?.id,
        }))
      );
    });
    setItems(itemsView);
  }, [orders]);
```